# How to make searchable list with unselected check box in to not visible div

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to make a searchable list with un-checked checkbox in to the not-visible div.

Question 1 : I have tried with the below program but search with checkbox are not working for inner html.

Question 2 : How to shift un-checked checkbox  to the bottom of INVISIBLE section.

I have attached the images below ...

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb5BF.png)

```js
function sortCols() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('colsearch');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("col-active");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12"> <span class="input-icon">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="colsearch" class="form-control colsearch" onkeyup="sortCols()">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </span>
                <div class="col-sm-12 well">VISIBLE </div>
                <ul id="col-active" class="media-list" style="margin-left: 10px">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"><div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Name" class="green" checked>
                        Name</label>
      </div></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"><div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="green" value="ProductCode" checked>
                        Product Code</label>
      </div></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"><div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="green" value="Active" checked>
                        Active </label>
      </div></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                   <a href="#"> <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="ID" class="green" checked>
        ID </label></a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"><div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Our Contact" class="green" checked>
                        Our Contact </label>
      </div></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                   <a href="#"> <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="PriceUSD" class="green" checked>
                        Price USD </label>
        </div></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                   <a href="#"> <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Our Contact" class="green" checked>
                        Our Contact </label>
        </div></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#"><div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Tax" class="green" checked>
                        Tax </label>
      </div></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                   <a href="#"> <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Unit" class="green" checked>
                        Unit </label>
        </div></a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="VisibleTo" class="green" checked>
                        Visible to </label>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="col-sm-12 well">INVISIBLE </div>
                <ul id="col-inactive" class="media-list"  style="margin-left: 10px">
                  <li>
                    <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Name" class="green" checked>
                        Name</label>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"> 
            <div class="btn-group floatright space10" style="margin-right: 10px;"> 
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xm sb-toggle" href="#toggleColumns">Cancel</a>           
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-xm" href="#">Save</a>    
             </div>       
           </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks its working now I need to shift un-checked checkbox to another div.

Comment: Did you modify your code from what you have posted in your question?  If so, and you still have remaining questions, please update your question to reflect what you are currently working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to shift un-checked checkbox to the bottom of INVISIBLE section you may listen for the change event for each checkbox and according to its state you may move the element in the first part or in the second part:

```
$(':checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
    if (this.checked == false && $(this).closest('#col-active').length == 1) {
        $(this).closest('li').appendTo('#col-inactive');
    }
    if (this.checked == true && $(this).closest('#col-inactive').length == 1) {
        $(this).closest('li').appendTo('#col-active');
    }
})
```

```js
function sortCols() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('colsearch');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("col-active");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("label")[0];
        if (a.textContent.trim().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

$(':checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
    if (this.checked == false && $(this).closest('#col-active').length == 1) {
        $(this).closest('li').appendTo('#col-inactive');
    }
    if (this.checked == true && $(this).closest('#col-inactive').length == 1) {
        $(this).closest('li').appendTo('#col-active');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12"> <span class="input-icon">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="colsearch" class="form-control colsearch" onkeyup="sortCols()">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </span>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 well">VISIBLE </div>
                    <ul id="col-active" class="media-list" style="margin-left: 10px">
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Name" class="green" checked>
                                    Name</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="green" value="ProductCode" checked>
                                    Product Code</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="green" value="Active" checked>
                                    Active </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="ID" class="green" checked>
                                    ID </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Our Contact" class="green" checked>
                                    Our Contact </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="PriceUSD" class="green" checked>
                                    Price USD </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Our Contact" class="green" checked>
                                    Our Contact </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Tax" class="green" checked>
                                    Tax </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Unit" class="green" checked>
                                    Unit </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="VisibleTo" class="green" checked>
                                    Visible to </label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 well">INVISIBLE </div>
                    <ul id="col-inactive" class="media-list"  style="margin-left: 10px">
                        <li>
                            <div class="checkbox sidebar-content">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Name" class="green" checked>
                                    Name</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I implement this one to your code ?


<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#productTable').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": "200px",
   dom: 'Alfrtip',
        "paging": false,
  alphabetSearch: { column: 0} 
    } );
 
    $('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
 
        // Get the column API object
        var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
 
        // Toggle the visibility
        column.visible( ! column.visible() );
    } );
} );
</script>

Comment: Also its not working and showing "This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!"